# Issue mounting Ubuntu NFSv4 share on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, ubuntu-16.04, nfs4

I'm having issues mounting an NFS share (Ubuntu 16.04) using NFSv4 on Windows 2012 R2 from what I understand 2012 R2 supports NFS v4.1, it looks to be defaulting to NFsv3 when running nfsstat -m.

I'm not sure if this is a server or client issue.

Answer (score 0):

NFS client on Windows Operating systems only support NFSv3:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/nfs/nfs-overview